# Windows 7 No Shortcut Tab on Desktop Icon

Tags: windows-7

OK, completely noob question I should be able to figure out but I am stuck.

I have a small program that I want to run in Windows 7 with a keyboard shortcut.  Selected Start -> Program In Question -> Right Click -> Send to (Create Shortcut on Desktop).

I want to add a keyboard shortcut to this, so I right click on the desktop shortcut and click properties.  Now I only have the following tabs: General, Security, Details, Previous Versions.  No option for Shortcut.

So, how do I create a custom keyboard shortcut from this desktop shortuct?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like that's not a shortcut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you made a folder shortcut, if it is a folder you won't have a shortcut tab, try it again but this time click the program you wanted to make a shortcut and see if it is just a folder that has a different icon. (If it expands in your start menu then it was a folder.)

Comment: I double checked and it is a program...but this a program I wrote with visual studio and when I hover over the shortcut icon I get this text: Type: ClickOnce Application Reference,  This is on the file I got after I did setup (not the folder but the file in it).

Comment: Hmm I don't know, those Visual Studio files (I'm assuming the express editions?) are pretty weird. I don't have it installed on this PC so I can't verify. Perhaps an alternative would be to go to the desktop and right click -> new -> shortcut and then figure out the path of that file by checking it's properties. I am not sure.

Comment: Not exactly the answer but that plus this page helped me get to it: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/how-run-clickonce-application

Comment: Ah, that is genius! I am glad you found it, I will bookmark that page.